# Angular - menu is not appearing

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, menu

I'm trying to implement a simple menu using angular and Ionic version 5, however the menu isn't showing up on the main home page. An Icon should be appearing at the top left hand side of the screen, where the user can click/tap it to reveal a drop-down menu of the items included in app.component.html My code is below

home.page.html

```
<ion-header [translucent]="true">
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title color = "light">
      EZ SWITCH FINANCE
      <ion-buttons slot = "start">
        <ion-menu-button menu="main-menu">
        </ion-menu-button>
      </ion-buttons>
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content [fullscreen]="true">
  <ion-header collapse="condense">
    <ion-toolbar>
      <ion-title size="large">Blank</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-header>

</ion-content>
```

app.component.htm

```
<ion-app>
  <ion-menu menuId = "main-menu" contentId="main">
    <ion-header>
      <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-title>
          Menu
        </ion-title>
      </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>
    <ion-content>
      <ion-list>

        <ion-item>
          <ion-icon name = "mail-outline" slot = "start"></ion-icon>
          <ion-label> Inbox </ion-label>
        </ion-item>

        <ion-item>
          <ion-icon name = "paper-plane-outline" slot = "start"></ion-icon>
          <ion-label> Outbox </ion-label>
        </ion-item>

        <ion-item>
          <ion-icon name = "heart-outline" slot = "start"></ion-icon>
          <ion-label> Favorites </ion-label>
        </ion-item>

        <ion-item>
          <ion-icon name="mail-outline" slot= "start"></ion-icon>
          <ion-label> Archived </ion-label>
        </ion-item>

        <ion-item>
          <ion-icon name = "trash-outline" slot = "start"></ion-icon>
          <ion-label> Trash </ion-label>
        </ion-item>

        <ion-item>
          <ion-icon name = "alert-outline" slot = "start"></ion-icon>
          <ion-label> Spam </ion-label>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-menu>
  <ion-router-outlet id="main"></ion-router-outlet>
</ion-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to get out of the "ion-menu-button" out of the "ion-buttons". If that doesnt work, you can always make a custom button with a click event and calling a method with this line of code:

```
    this.menu.open('theIdOfMyMenuId');
```

Comment: when you say "try to get out of the "ion-menu-button" out of the "ion-buttons" what do you mean?

Comment: Removing the "ion-buttons" tag and just letting the "ion-menu-button"

Comment: Because it doesnt need the ion-buttons tag, probably wrapping it up an doesnt let the click event get through :P

Comment: Hello! if my response was helpful i would appreciate a lot if you can vote it as solution :)